# How to install pre-release python packages in setup.py install_requires section?

Tags: python, dependencies, setuptools

In case a python package has a dependency to external libraries we can do:

```
from setuptools import setup
setup(name='funniest',
      version='0.1',
      description='The funniest joke in the world',
      url='http://github.com/storborg/funniest',
      author='Flying Circus',
      author_email='flyingcircus@example.com',
      license='MIT',
      packages=['funniest'],
      install_requires=[
          'markdown',
      ],
      zip_safe=False)
```

If I want to install pre-release version of a package in `install_requires` what should I do? I could not find any flag or command in `setuptools`, that could do so?

What is the solution for installing unstable pre-release version of packages in `install_requires`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Declaring the version explicitly works.

```
install_requires=[
    'marshmallow>=3.0.0b11'
]
```

Comment: For more information, see: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0440/#compatible-release and https://stackoverflow.com/a/64319551/2954547