# Pre-release versions are not matched by pip when using the `--pre` option

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, setup.py, pypi

Imagine you have published two pre-releases:

```
 package 0.0.1.dev0
 package 0.0.2.dev0
```

My `install_requires` section in `setup.py` states:

```
[
    'package>=0.0.2,<1.0.0'
]
```

Now, when i run `pip install . --upgrade --pre` I get an error:

> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement package<1.0.0,>=0.0.2 (from versions: 0.0.1.dev0, 0.0.2.dev0)
> ERROR: No matching distribution found for package<1.0.0,>=0.0.2

What am I doing wrong? Isn't the `--pre` flag supposed to tell pip to match pre-release versions?

Comment: There is a deleted answer by @ChristopherPeisert here that may give the answer. Per PEP 440, 0.0.2.dev0 comes _prior_ in version history to 0.0.2, a "final release." Therefore, neither of those published packages are matched by your requirements specifier. It would seem that `--pre` operates independently of that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Summary

The pip `--pre` option directs pip to include potential matching pre-release and development versions, but it does not change the semantics of version matching.

Since pre-release `0.0.2.dev0` is older than stable release `0.0.2`, pip correctly reports an error when searching for a package that is at least as new as stable release `0.0.2`.

#### Explanation

The key point of confusion is around the pip `--pre` option, which is documented as:

> `--pre`
> Include pre-release and development versions. By default, pip only finds stable versions.

The premise of the question is that the `--pre` option should change the package-version-matching semantics such that pre-release version suffixes would be ignored when matching against stable versions.

To further clarify, consider the compatible release operator **`~=`**. PEP 440 section [**Compatible release**](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0440/#compatible-release), states in part:

> For a given release identifier `V.N`, the compatible release clause is approximately equivalent to the pair of comparison clauses:
>
> `>= V.N, == V.*`
>
> ...
>
> If a pre-release, post-release or developmental release is named in a compatible release clause as `V.N.suffix`, then the suffix is ignored when determining the required prefix match:
>
> ~= 2.2.post3
> = 2.2.post3, == 2.*
>
> ~= 1.4.5a4
> = 1.4.5a4, == 1.4.*

This example makes it clear that the *suffix* is ignored.

The following requirement does not match `0.0.2.dev0`:

```
install_requires=['package~=0.0.2']  # ERROR: ResolutionImpossible
```

Whereas this example *does* match stable release `0.0.2`:

```
install_requires=['package~=0.0.2.dev0']  # OK - suffix ignored
```